# function to output list is not working

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that takes a parameter number integer, and outputs the list part of that number. so for example if we have

```
 List = ["Hello world", "james bond"]
```

We create a function that takes a parameter number and outputs the right part of the list

This is the code I have

```
documentNum = input("What is the document number ?")
    createList(documentNum)

def createList(documentNum):
        List = ["Hello world", "james bond"] 
        print(List[documentNum])
```

so if we enter 1

I expect to get James bond

However I am getting instead that

> List indices must be integers, not str

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: BTW... This seems to be Python 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
documentNum = int(input("What is the document number ?"))
```